# Select lists that don't contain a given element (was: elements in a list (all elements should be satisfied))

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a big list, for simple, it just like:

```
list = {
        {1, Overflow[], 3}, 
        {Overflow[], Overflow[], 7}, 
        {Overflow[], 4, 2}, {7, 8, 9},
        {-1, Overflow[], 3}, {-1, 10, 10}
       };
```

I don't know where contain `Overflow[]`, so I want to filter the list by `Select[]` function, If `Overflow[]` at the first position, I know it will work by:

```
Select[list, Not[#[[1]] == Overflow[]] &]
```

It will return `{{1, Overflow[], 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {-1, Overflow[], 3}, {-1, 10, 10}}`

**Is there any way to check all the positions, return `{{7, 8, 9}, {-1, 10, 10}}`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[list, FreeQ[Overflow[]]]
(* {{7, 8, 9}, {-1, 10, 10}} *)

Select[list, Not@*MemberQ[Overflow[]]]
(* {{7, 8, 9}, {-1, 10, 10}} *)

Select[list, ContainsNone[{Overflow[]}]]
(* {{7, 8, 9}, {-1, 10, 10}} *)
```

Comment: Your answer is well done.